# Why won't this code work in IE11, Chrome, Firefox, but will work in IE8?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

My developer at work tossed me a small template so I could edit it and make a mockup for a work thing.  When he created it, it worked just fine; he made it in IE8.  When he emailed it to me and I opened it in IE11/Chrome/Firefox no go.  Any assistance?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function handleVisibility(box){
    var visible = (box.checked) ? "block": "none";
    box.parentElement.nextSibling.style.display = visible;       
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  
   <div id="divTransfer">
    <input id="cbTransferRefer" type="checkbox" value="TransferRefer" onClick = "handleVisibility(this)">Transfer/Refer<br>
   </div>
   <div  id="pTransferTypes" style="display:none" >
    Transfer Types: 
    <select>
      <option value="referred">Referred</option>
      <option value="internalTaskForm">Escalated via Internal Task Form</option>
      <option value="cci">Escalated via CCI</option>
      <option value="pdf">Escalated via PDF Form</option>
      <option value="transferred">Transferred</option>
    </select> 
   </div>
   
   
   <div id="divTemplate">
    <input id="cbTemplateRefer" type="checkbox" value="TemplateRefer" onClick = "handleVisibility(this)">Template/Refer<br>
   </div>
   <div  id="pTemplateTypes" style="display:none" >
    Template Types: 
    <select>
      <option value="referred">Referred</option>
      <option value="internalTaskForm">Escalated via Internal Task Form</option>
      <option value="cci">Escalated via CCI</option>
      <option value="pdf">Escalated via PDF Form</option>
      <option value="transferred">Transferred</option>
    </select> 
   </div>
  
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Try calling `nextElementSibling` instead of `nextSibling`.

Comment: Only two check boxes should be visible with text after them.  Selecting a check box will populate a drop down under it, sliding the lower checkbox and text down to make room.  Currently, selecting the check boxes does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily want the `nextSibling`, you want the `nextElementSibling`. If there is white-space after your parent element, the next sibling will be *that* white-space. As such, you would want to either remove all white-space between the element, and its sibling, or call `nextElementSibling` to guarantee you don't get a textNode.

It's worth noting that `getElementSibling` is only supported in IE 9 and above. But, if you need IE 8 support, you can simply remove the white-space, keeping `nextSibling`, or [leverage a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling#Polyfill_for_Internet_Explorer_8).

Comment: Well that works obviously.  Thanks!  Now, so this isn't just a "fix my problem" thread, can you give a short education on the difference between the two?  I'm slowly learning a little more code as I work on mock ups.

Comment: Sure, `nextSibling` returns the next item, regardless what it is. It could be an element or a textNode. Only an element is going to be styleable though. By calling `nextElementSibling`, you grab the nearest element sibling (which may be after some white-space/textNodes).